# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

The code below is producing &quot instead of normal quotes causing javascript to read my asp variable incorrectly. I even http utility decoded it and same issue.

```
    @{
        string labels = "";

        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            labels = labels + "\"" + item.Month + "\",";
        }
        labels = labels.TrimEnd(',');
    }

    var salesChartData = {
        labels: [@labels],
        datasets: [
```

labels comes accross as

```
labels: [&quot;April&quot;,&quot;July&quot;,&quot;February&quot;,&quot;May&quot;,&quot;June&quot;,&quot;March&quot;]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Razor HTML-encodes everything that is output on the page, including quotes. To force raw output, use [Html.Raw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg480740%28v=VS.118%29.aspx):

```
labels: [@Html.Raw(labels)],
```